# Set of all primes $p$ that split in $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{-k}\right)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, number-fields, quadratic-residues

Let $k$ be a squarefree positive integer. We know that a prime $p$ splits in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-k})$ if and only if $-k$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$.

My question is: can we explicitly determine the set of all primes that split in $K$ for a certain parametrized $k$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The following answer concerns the original version of the question, while my comment below addresses the updated version.

For $p>3$ the Chinese Remainder Theorem shows that there are integers $k\equiv 11\pmod{24}$ such that $-k$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Oh, so $3$ is the only prime that splits in $K$ for $k\equiv11\pmod{24}$?

Comment: @user491084 Yes, $p=3$ is the only prime that splits simultaneously in every $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-k})$ for $k\equiv 11\pmod{24}$. If you like my answer, please accept it officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure, I have now edited the question and asked in a more general context :)

Comment: @user491084 My answer should make it clear that the answer to your general question is also yes. The prime $p$ must divide the modulus of the arithmetic progression of the $k$'s, and for such a prime either every $-k$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ or every $-k$ is a quadratic non-residue modulo $p$ (which can be checked by plugging in the relevant residue into the quadratic residue symbol modulo $p$).

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thanks!!!

Comment: @user491084 OK, so by "parametrized $k$" you meant "$k$ lying in a given arithmetic progression". Please update your question to reflect this precise meaning, and then accept my answer officially (so that it turns green). Thanks in advance!